# POSTGIS intersection query is a extremely slow

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have two spatial postgis layers tablea(polygon) and tableb(multipolygon) and I want to create a postgis query to take a new intersection polygon layer.

here the postgis query :

```
CREATE TABLE myschema.new_table_int AS(
  SELECT myschema.tablaa.field1 AS field1,
         myschema.tableb.fieldb AS fieldb,
         (st_dump(
           ST_CollectionExtract(
           st_intersection(
              myschema.tablaa.geom,
              myschema.tableb.geom)::GEOMETRY(GEOMETRY,4326),3))).geom AS shape 
  FROM  myschema.tablaa, 
        myschema.tableb 
  WHERE st_intersects(myschema.tablaa.geom,myschema.tableb.geom))
```

that code works fine but is extremely slow.

Is there a faster way to populate the table?

**update**

table a have over 250000 features

table b have over 10000 features

the calculate time cost is over 2 hours

here example :

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Comment: do you have an index on the two geometry columns?

Comment: @JHG yes I have

Comment: Performance questions ***really*** need to include row counts and the EXPLAIN plan of the optimizer. You should also include the exact database and extension release numbers. Finally,  "slow" should be quantified (in seconds or milliseconds)

Comment: @Vince I have update

Comment: Okay, now add the EXPLAIN plan. You have smallish table counts, so even two or three minutes would be too long. You really need to learn how to use `JOIN` syntax, which will give you better query control. Since you seem to be casting, please specify the storage type and SRID of each table.

Comment: @Vince I say I my question is my first query in postgis,that layers have common SRID,tell me your proposal

Comment: shot in the dark.. try a WITH with st_intersects to first get the geometries you wish to treat then do the dump on the reduced records. It may inherently do this but it is worth a shot. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html Perhaps the warning on ST_CollectionExtract may have something to do with your experience https://postgis.net/docs/ST_CollectionExtract.html

Comment: If the SRIDs are identical, your cast causes a full table scan for naught.

Comment: @user92055 can you show me some example with a `WITH`

Comment: I still don't see the query plan. Please add the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.